# plotting a grouped bar chart with bins

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have a dataframe similar to like this:

```
Create Date    count1 count2 count3 count4
2018-01          12     21     12    123
2018-02          11     25     12    145
2018-08          12     26     12    145
2019-03          13     28     12    334
2019-06          15     22     12    345
2019-07          16     25     12    165
2020-01          12     25     12    178
2020-02          12     23     12    178
2020-03          12     26     12    187
2021-01          11     28     12    146
2021-02          12     29     12    123
2021-03          11     22     12    189
2022-01          17     21     12    167
2022-02          18     23     12    166
2022-03          19     23     12    123
```

I want a grouped bar chart where x axis is a year. For example 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022.
In each of those year I want the sum of a column in that year as 1 bar and so on.

What I tried

```
    df_combined.plot.bar(logy=True)
    plt.xticks(rotation=0)
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```

What I am getting is a crowded bar chart like this[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a [`pandas.DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) by using [`groupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) before calling [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) :

```
(
  df_combined
        .assign(year= pd.DatetimeIndex(df_combined["Create Date"]).year)
        .groupby("year").sum(numeric_only=True) #as_index=True by default
        .plot(kind="bar", logy=True)
)

plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc="upper left")
plt.show();
```

Output (*plot*) :

[image]

Comment: i am getting following error - ```TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid. Use `data.to_timestamp()` instead```

Comment: I assume that the `df_combined` in my answer correspond to the example your shared. If so, this code should work without any problems.